# Is it "on behalf of" or "in behalf of"?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

I often hear folks say *in behalf of* instead of *on behalf of*, which sets my teeth on edge.

Which preposition is correct here, *in* or *on*?

Answer (score 1):

According to [Oxford online](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/behalf) it is both correct:

> in phrase on (US also in) behalf of or on someone's/something's behalf

I have to say that personally I would also use *on* behalf. I went to the dictionary thinking it would only show that.

Comment: Beat me to it. I thought "in behalf of" was wrong, turns out it is accepted usage.

Answer (score 0):

I have never heard *in behalf of* used. But [this Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=in+behalf+of%3Aeng_us_2012%2Con+behalf+of%3Aeng_us_2012%2Cin+behalf+of%3Aeng_br_2012%2Con+behalf+of%3Aeng_br_2012&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cin%20behalf%20of%3Aeng_us_2012%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Con%20behalf%20of%3Aeng_us_2012%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cin%20behalf%20of%3Aeng_br_2012%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Con%20behalf%20of%3Aeng_br_2012%3B%2Cc0) says that it has been used (but decreasingly so).

As to whether it is "*correct*" or not, who is to say? You decide.